# Replace static value by value which is present in database

Tags: magento-1.9, database

We are using below  code to display **"Unpaid/Paid"** as Paid status.

```
 if ($roworders['dproduct_id'] == '')
                    {
                    $dorderStatus = "Unpaid";
                    }
                  else
                    {
                    $dorderStatus = $roworders['dpaid_status'];
                    }
```

[image]

[image]

in database, for **product ID - 15517** , it showing status as **Paid**, so in **site**, i want to replace "Unpaid" by "Paid".

```
 $i = 0;
    foreach($order as $orderData)
        {
        $orderitems = $orderData['dproduct_id'];
        $orderitemsarray = explode(",", $orderitems);
        $k = 0;
        $oDate = new DateTime($orderData['created_at']);
        $sDate = $oDate->format("Y-m-d");
        while ($k < count($orderitemsarray))
            {
            if ($orderitemsarray[$k] != '0')
                {
                $stmtorders = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE designerorder_id=:designerorder_id");
                $stmtorders->execute(array(
                    ":designerorder_id" => $orderData['entity_id']
                ));
                $roworders = $stmtorders->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                if ($roworders['dproduct_id'] == '')
                    {
                    $dorderStatus = "Unpaid";
                    }
                  else
                    {
                    $dorderStatus = $roworders['dpaid_status'];
                    }

                if ($roworders['designerorder_id'] == '')
                    {
                    $commission = "comm";
                    }
                  else
                    {
                    $dorderStatus = $roworders['commission'];
                    }

                $productdetail = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($orderitemsarray[$k]);
                $designerName = getDesignerName($productdetail->getDesignerID()) . " -(" . $productdetail->getDesignerID() . ")";
                $responce[] = array(
                    $orderData->getIncrementId() ,
                    $orderData->getIncrementId() ,
                    $orderitemsarray[$k],
                    $productdetail->getName() ,
                    $designerName,
                    $orderData['status'],
                    $orderData['grand_total'],
                    $orderData['customer_email'],
                    $commission,
                    $dorderStatus,
                    $sDate
                );
                }

            $k++;
            $i++;
            }
        }

    echo json_encode($responce);
    }
```

**script**

```
{id: 'dpaid_status' , header: "Paid status" , width :"80"},
```

**Edit**

when i tried this [code](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphpfile.asp?filename=demo_db_select_oo) , its fetching results from database.....

Comment: Which value is return in above $roworders['dpaid_status']

Comment: @Rakesh i tried this code : `echo $roworders['dpaid_status'];` after line `if ($roworders['dproduct_id'] == '')
     {
     $commission = "comm";
     }
      else
     {
     $commission = $roworders['commission'];
     }` , its displaying nothing.....

Comment: but in your table commission field is not display

Comment: please check here complete table : http://prnt.sc/ddwu9l , i pasted only required values in question.....

Comment: i think you have not getting value for $commision right?

Comment: @Rakesh for commission also i have same problem..... its displaying `comm` instead of value present in db....

Comment: have you geting value for $roworders['commission']? Have you checked array? i think you have mistake for $dorderStatus = $roworders['commission']; here you have to give $commision = $roworders['commission'];

Comment: @Rakesh when i tried this code : `echo var_dump($roworders['commission']); `   result `Notice: Undefined variable: roworders in &   
`NULL`

Comment: jsut print var_dump($roworders) and check which value is returned

Comment: @Rakesh stil same error : `Notice: Undefined variable: roworders `    & `NULL`

Comment: You have issue in your query you have to debug from first line of foreach and check

Comment: fine @Rakesh,  i ll try to debug, this is complete code : http://pastebin.com/pic9FUdv , when you get free time , please go through once.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this portion of your code is not working.

```
$stmtorders = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE designerorder_id=:designerorder_id");
$stmtorders->execute(array(
    ":designerorder_id" => $orderData['entity_id']
));
$roworders = $stmtorders->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Add this line code below above code : `echo '<pre>';print_r($roworders);die;` and check.

First you have to check any record you are getting or not from this query . If not then its a issue of fetching the record from query.

In that case use `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to enable error and check the error.

replace this code

```
$responce[] = array(
    $orderData->getIncrementId() ,
    $orderData->getIncrementId() ,
    $orderitemsarray[$k],
    $productdetail->getName() ,
    $designerName,
    $orderData['status'],
    $orderData['grand_total'],
    $orderData['customer_email'],
    $orderData['commission'],
    $orderData['dpaid_status'],
//  $commission,
//  $dorderStatus,
    $sDate
);
```

form

```
$responce[] = array(
    $orderData->getIncrementId() ,
    $orderData->getIncrementId() ,
    $orderitemsarray[$k],
    $productdetail->getName() ,
    $designerName,
    $orderData['status'],
    $orderData['grand_total'],
    $orderData['customer_email'],
    $orderData['commission'],
    $dorderStatus, // change this line
//  $commission,
//  $dorderStatus,
    $sDate
);
```

Comment: i tried this code : `echo '<pre>';print_r($roworders);die;` after that `order grid table` did't displayed , also after that i tried `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` but it didt displayed any errors......

Comment: sorry, still i didt found any error......

Comment: when i tried this [code](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphpfile.asp?filename=demo_db_select_oo) , its fetching results from database.....

Comment: okay, but when i tried this : `echo '<pre>';print_r($roworders);die;` order grid table disappeared.....

Comment: please check full code : http://pastebin.com/bcLzZaKL

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time for checking thousand lines of code ..... I removed \\  & i did some changes, now only first row value in db is  fetching and displaying same value for all rows.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento check my updated answer. and remove `'<pre>';print_r($roworders);die;`

Comment: i removed `'<pre>';print_r($roworders);die;` in db  : http://prnt.sc/dgrjwb , in site : http://prntscr.com/dgrjzb

Comment: means its fetching first value of first row in db and displaying same value fro all rows.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento, Have you updated code as per my updated answer ?

Comment: please check updated code : http://pastebin.com/dXEVadTh

Comment: yes , i updated as per your code.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento, are you getting $commission text proper in grid ?

Comment: same issue for commission also, fetching `first row` value in db and displaying same value for `all rows` in site.....